# Will revisions be retained when converting to a multi-site?

Tags: multisite, revisions

Will revisions be retained when converting to a multi-site?

We’re looking to convert a WordPress site to a multi-site, and the client we’re working with is very conscious that they don’t want to lose any revisions data.

I can’t find anything in the codex about data loss when converting to a multi-site, but is it a possibility that we might lose some of this data when converting the site?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisions are stored as posts in the `*_posts` table(s). This shouldn't be touched during a conversion to Multisite.

I just did a quick test on my local machine:

- Installed WordPress
- Added a couple pages and posts
- Revised the pages and posts
- Made sure the revisions were stored in the DB
- Ran the Multisite conversion from the command line (`wp core multisite-convert`)
- Checked to make sure the revisions were still stored in the DB

It appears that the conversion did not affect the revisions at all.

However, note that *your mileage may vary*. I'd recommend doing a full database backup before running the conversion to Multisite. (I'd recommend doing that in any event, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. Sounds good to me!